# Beyond Compare left/right file ordering using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, beyondcompare

The left/right files in BeyondCompare merge are reversed when using `hg fetch` vs an `hg pull` + `hg merge`.  Is there any reason for this?  Is there a way to keep the same configuration?

---

**Update:**

Related question/answer: [Completely manual Mercurial merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685151/completly-manual-mercurial-merge/685171#685171)

Comment: It's not the answer you want, but you really shouldn't use `fetch` -- it's disabled for a reason.  Separating pulling and then updating or merging into separate actions allows both of them to give better output.  Why should your file transfer be rolled back just because you abort a merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a reason. From `hg help fetch`:

> When a merge occurs, the newly pulled changes are assumed to be "authoritative". The head of the new changes is used as the first parent, with local changes as the second. To switch the merge order, use --switch-parent.

This means a fetch is similar to the following manual workflow:

1. pull
2. update to new pulled head
3. merge

Using the `--switch-parent` option skips step 2 and thus prevents a *reversed* merge.